# Is there any word for describing something that is about time?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

**Is there any word for describing something that is about time ?**

For example," ... you can not do that either for financial reasons or [something about time] reasons"

Comment: "Temporal" will do. It can have a wider meaning, of course, but you would be understood. Alternatively, you could say "time-related".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes people refer to "scheduling reasons" (difficulty in fitting something into a schedule) or "logistical reasons" (planning reasons).  "Time reasons" is occasionally used but is a fairly uncommon usage and doesn't sound particularly natural here.

I would say:

> You cannot do so for reasons of either time or money
>
> You cannot do so either for financial reasons or due to time constraints
>
> You cannot do so due to constraints of either time or money

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a word meaning "of or relating to time"; it's "temporal".

Comment: Yes, but it fits poorly here.